# What structure should post_content have in the database?

Tags: posts, database

Let me start off by saying that I have no WordPress experience at all so I may be asking a really stupid question. What I need to do is transfer a bunch of articles from a old MySQL database to a WordPress site.

Now I found wp_insert_post and I can get all the data from the old DB. The problem starts with the article images. In the WordPress DB there seems to be a `<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><img src="hard path to image here" alt="" class="wp-image-4066"/></figure>` tag that points to the exact image. Problem is that it is surrounded by, what I would call strange comments, that look like this :

```
<!-- wp:image {"id":4066,"sizeSlug":"large"} -->
<!-- /wp:image -->
```

This id seems to be the ID of the image that is made a attachment type post in the same table. My question is are these comments necessary or can I just generate the  tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those comments have been added by the Gutenberg block editor. If you remove them you'll no longer be able to edit those blocks in the admin using Gutenberg.

Comment: but will WordPress display the page as it is? Since I need to transfer old articles being able to edit them is not a concern.

Comment: If they're standard blocks they should still display correctly even without the comments, yes.

Comment: Thank you very much :)